# Why is Mongo assigning an id to this field?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Why is Mongo assigning an id to some fields and not others?

```
var mongoose = require ("mongoose");
var mySchema = new mongoose.Schema ({   

// other fields...
```

_id assigned to this field:

```
packageEdits: [{
    time: Date,
    section: String,
    fields: [String]
}],
```

but not here:

```
subtitles: {
    path: String,
    fileName: String
},

// other fields...
})
```

When viewed in Mongo, there's an _id assigned to this field:

```
"packageEdits" : [
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("44cfedfdf34ca223aa3411aa"),
    "section" : "someSection",
    "time" : ISODate("2016-02-25T19:05:49.055Z"),
    "fields" : [
        "someValue"
    ]
}
],
```

But not here:

```
"subtitles" : {
"path" : "/some/path",
"fileName" : "someName"
},
```

Does this help with querying these nested properties?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not MongoDB that is doing this but `mongoose`. If you don't want it, then assign a separate "Schema" for "packageEdits" and set the `{ "_id": false }` option on it:

```
// Separate schema
var packageEditSchema = new Schema({
    time: Date,
    section: String,
    fields: [String]
},{
    "_id": false
});

// Main schema
var mySchema = new Schema({
    // ... other fields
    packageEdits: [packageEditSchema]
});
```

Mongoose deems it to be a "good idea" to assign a unique identifier ( `_id` field ) to every array element specified directly within a schema, with the exception of course with an explicit type. i.e `"fields": [String]`.

It is somewhat handy to keep the identifier, and for several reasons, but if you decide you really don't want it then just specify the option to turn this mongoose behavior off.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that these objects are within a larger object. If that is the case, then "subtitles" already has a unique identifier from one or more levels up the parent chain. "packageEdits" can be found using its parent identifier as well. However, "packageEdits" has an array of objects inside of it. Therefore, mongoDb needs to set an address for all of the array elements by giving it an id. This is needed for several reasons, but the best in my option is, if an array were to change for whatever reason you can not rely on an index to give you a specific object and usually every object in an array will have identical keys. So in order to reliably call specific objects from an array you need to have a unique address.

Comment: "seems that these objects are within a larger object" – Hmm, the collection mySchema isn't, and neither are `subtitles`, `packageEdits`, or any of those objects' properties. For the array, couldn't it be addressed by the property name, "fields"? Thank you

Comment: I would have to look at your data structures to know better how to explain it. I just googled it to double check and this comes straight from MongoDB:  "MongoDB uses ObjectIds as the default value for the _id field if the _id field is not specified; i.e. if a document does not contain a top-level _id field, the MongoDB driver adds the _id field that holds an ObjectId. In addition, if the mongod receives a document to insert that does not contain an _id field, mongod will add the _id field that holds an ObjectId." [MongoDB ref](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/object-id/)